# Como alinear 2 div dentro de una tabla

Tags: html, css

Buen dia, estoy intentando alinear una tabla, específicamente una columna `td`, lo que deseo es agregar 2 valores y alinearlos dentro de un `td`.

Así es como se ve hasta el momento mi tabla;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte de mi código.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Module / Role</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 1
      </td>
      <td> Status 1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;">MODULO 1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;"><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 2
      </td>
      <td> Status 2
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;">MODULO MUCHO MAS GRANDE 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;"><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Cabe resaltar que el código esta bien, solo necesito el estilo y que la parte de Module/Role, se alinee Modulo al mismo nivel a la izquierda, y los roles igual, sin necesidad de usar otra columna, gracias.

Dejo una imagen de lo que quiero lograr. En realidad, lograr que todo se alinee.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pregunta ¿por qué metiste los valores de módulo y rol dentro de dos divs?

Comment: son valores que en realidad traigo desde el Back, podria ponerlos juntos, no hay problema, lo que pasa es que quiero que se alineen tanto por modulo y por rol. no se si haya otra forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Aunque @phpMyGuel te ofrece una solución que me gusta, veo que en algunas líneas hay dobles entradas. Para facilitar eso podrías hacer lo siguiente: El tercer th extendido sobre dos columnas así `<th colspan="2">Module/role</th>` y en las líneas interiores asignar cada valor en su celda. Obviamente, algunas celdas en las columnas 1 y 2 irán vacías cuando la línea debe contener asignaciones dobles. Nota: al tercer th debes asignarle una clase para darle un estilo centrado de modo que se vea bien el conjunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar las ventajas que te ofrecen las **cajas flexibles**.

Si haces que el `<td>` que contiene tus dos columnas (*module* y *role*) tenga la propiedad `display: flex` y además usas `justify-content: space-between` conseguirás esa alineación que buscas.

Para darles esas propiedades cree una clase y se la añadí a los `<td>` en cuestión.

```css
.alineado {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Para dar una separación entre las dos columnas del <td> */
.alineado div:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Module / Role</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 1
      </td>
      <td> Status 1
      </td>
      <td class="alineado">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;">MODULO 1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;"><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 2
      </td>
      <td> Status 2
      </td>
      <td class="alineado">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;">MODULO MUCHO MAS GRANDE 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;"><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Aunque mi solución funciona con el ejemplo que se facilita, me percaté de que si existe diferencia de tamaño entre los textos de *role* vuelve a descuadrarse. Por ello considero esta segunda solución que quizá de ajuste más a lo que necesitas.

```css
.alineado div {
  float: left;
}

.alineado div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 60%;
}

.alineado div:nth-child(even) {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Module / Role</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 1
      </td>
      <td> Status 1
      </td>
      <td class="alineado">
        <div>MODULO 1</div>
        <di><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email 2
      </td>
      <td> Status 2
      </td>
      <td class="alineado">
        <div>MODULO MUCHO MAS GRANDE 2</div>
        <div><span style="color:green">ROL MÁS GRANDE</span></div>
        <div>Oootro</div>
        <div><span style="color:green">OTRO ROL</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, justo lo aplique y dio con normalidad.

Comment: Modifiqué un poco la segunda solución para adaptarse a lo que comenta el colega @quevedo y poder así contemplar el caso de un `<td>` con más de un par de valores *Module / Role*.

Comment: Gracias, lo revisare igual.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... No lo entiendos, lo que quieres hacer es esto?

```html
                    <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Module / Role</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Email 1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Status 1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 d-inline">MODULO 1</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 d-inline" style="display: inline;"><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Email 2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Status 2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 d-inline">MODULO MUCHO MAS GRANDE 2</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 d-inline"><span style="color:green">ROL 1</span></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal ves solo es agregar `text-align: center`  a los estilos de tu td, es recomendable que tambien utilices un *thead*

```html
<table class="table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Module / Role</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Email 1</td>
      <td>Status 1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;">MODULO 1</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline;"><span style="color: green;">ROL 
      1</span></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Email 2</td>
      <td>Status 2</td>
      <td>
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline; text-align: center;">MODULO MUCHO MAS 
      GRANDE 2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: inline; text-align: center;"><span 
      style="color:green;">ROL 1</span></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

el código aquí